# Not able to detect third screen on onboard VGA

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, display

Does somebody have some experience with the following problem.
I just remasterd from Xp to Windows 7(32-bit) a HP desktop with aditional Nvidia graphic card.
The graphic card allows the users to use 3 screens(needed to use severall applications at the same time) and when they where working on Xp it worked fine but now on Windows 7 the VGA on the motherboard doesn't seem to detect the screen anymore.
The other 2 screens are detected without any problem via the split on the Nvidia graphic card
BIOS settings are adapted and correct.
Thanks for the feedback.

With Kind Regards,

Michael

Comment: The multiple screen support is handled by the graphic card's video driver. What version of the nvidia driver are you using?

Comment: Hi, It is a HP Desktop so I checked on the HP site wich driver to use with Windows 7 (32-bit) On the HP site it is version 8.17.12.7635 from this year (sp55785.exe)

Comment: You didn't list the graphics card model number. Nvida driver version numbers are more like "295.73". The V8.17... might be a HP repackaging of an older driver. I would use the NVidiea update tool to check for latest and support.

Comment: Hi, Thks again, I will do and keep you informed :-)